# Empty tables are squeezed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am trying to generate tables with random sizes, such as **n * n** where n can be between 3 to 7. The tables should be reponsive and should fit wholly on any device screen.

**Problem:**
When the table is generated all the cells are squeezed up and if I add data into the any cell, other cells squeeze up while that particular cell expands.

**What I want:**
I want all the cells to be **responsive** and **square** in shape too. By square I mean when the table is generated, each cell should be width = height. And the table as whole should nicely fit the viewport.

**What I did:**
I used a bit of JS to make each cell reponsive but on larger screens each cell turned out to be huge, resulting in a huge table, which overflows the height of the viewport.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></span> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--<div class="centerMe">-->
        <div class="container">
            <table id="board" class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td data-cell="0"></td>
                    <td data-cell="1"></td>
                    <td data-cell="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-cell="3"></td>
                    <td data-cell="4"></td>
                    <td data-cell="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-cell="6"></td>
                    <td data-cell="7"></td>
                    <td data-cell="8"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <!--</div>-->
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*$(document).ready(function() {
    function  resizetable() {
        var newBoxHeight= $('td').outerWidth();
        $('td').outerHeight(newBoxHeight);
    }
    resizetable();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizetable();
    });
});*/
</script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}
.site-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     border-top: 5px solid #5A332B;
     background-color: #ccbb99 !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
 }
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #683F36;
}
.navbar-brand {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: chalkitup, "sans-serif";
}
.centerMe {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-60%);
}
.site-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-top: 5px solid #5A332B;
    background-color: #ccbb99 !important;
}
#board, #board td {
    border: none;
}
#board td:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#board td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
#board td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
#board tr {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#board tr:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
#board tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #board {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 70%;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I am using twitter-bootstrap 3.

Comment: May I know which part is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You want the table cells to be square and there are only three cells in each row. The width of each row is assigned to the height. It will obviously create huge boxes. If square boxes are not necessary, then you can set the height of the boxes manually so they do not look too big.

Comment: Square boxes are a necessary, and the code above is an example. As I already mentioned, the table can be 3*3 to 7*7

Comment: You want the table to be square or individual cells to be square?

Comment: If all cells become square then definitely the whole table will become a square as I will be maintaining n * n perspective

Comment: Then if you don't want huge tables then set the width of the table and display it in the center of the screen. Both your problems will be solved that way. Also, if this does not help, please elaborate what you want exactly.

Comment: I have already set a dynamic value 70% of the container div. If I make it a fixed value then it would look horrible on large screens.

Comment: Try setting 70% width to table, not the container and give margin as auto. It will position your table on the center of the screen.

Comment: Am sorry, I made a mistake in my comment, I have set 70% width to the table. Not the div. See the html structure and css.

Comment: Check this link and if possible send a screenshot so that I can know what exactly do u want. : http://codepen.io/shalineesingh/pen/LxBPoo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134977/discussion-between-ayan-and-shalinee-singh).

Comment: If I enter values in the cells, it changes its shape.